# Can't access node http server from external IP

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've node application which work fine on my localhost, but whenever I try to access it from external IP, it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res){
     res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
     res.end('My node server is working!!');
}).listen(3000);
```

Any help is apreciated,

Thank's in advance

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It is probably a network routing issue.

Comment: My firewall is desactivated, I'm on Windows 7

Comment: I found the solution, I just opened the port I wanna listen to on my router

Comment: Can you please share the steps you did to make it works ?